# How to create a dropdown form using jquery and stripes?

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button, stripes

I've recently got to know the Stripes framework and is implementing it in one of my project. I'm trying to create a dynamic form consisting of radio-buttoned questions. I've used the  functions to code.

I've tried to use jQuery but it seems to give me errors.

For example, the user selected this:

```
`<stripes:radio name="place" value="a"/>a
 <stripes:radio name="place" value="b"/>b
 <stripes:radio name="place" value="c"/>c
```

After clicking on the option, it will show the next question, similar to the abovementioned. 
However, when I implement `function () {$(stripes:radio).show()}` to link to the next question, it doesn't show.

Am I going on the right track or is there any better ways to solve this?

I apologize if I'm not clear enough. I'm still new to this and please guide me along. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The '[show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)' method is only available on a JQuery object, thus you should use a JQuery selector to get such an object (has nothing to do with Stripes, as Stripes is server side and JQuery runs in the browser!). For example:

```
function() {  $('#radiobuttons').show) }
```

This will make this block of HTML visible:

```
<div id="radiobuttons">
  <stripes:radio name="place" value="a"/>a    
  <stripes:radio name="place" value="b"/>b    
  <stripes:radio name="place" value="c"/>c
</div>
```